# Modify WordPress Page Title Outside of Header.php

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to programmatically assign the page title outside of the header.php file?

In one of my page template files, I would like to dynamically assign the page title based on a value in a custom field. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use a filter hook to assign a value to wp_title:

```
function assignPageTitle(){
  return "Title goes here";
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'assignPageTitle');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I use in header.php to set the title dynamically. You could use something similar to get your custom field value.

```
if (is_single() && have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  echo "OKC ThunderCast: ".get_the_title();
  rewind_posts(); //needed so that the call to The Loop on single.php will find the posts
} else {
  bloginfo('name');
}
```

Comment: This is still using code inside header.php.  I'm wanting to try to do this outside of the header.php file.  Is this possible?

Comment: You could write some dynamic JavaScript to set the title (document.title = "x"), but that wouldn't be picked up by Google or any client that isn't executing JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, I really want it to be picked up by facebook and other search engines.